# JComboBox - no ItemEvents for null-items

Tags: java, swing

It seems no selected or deselected `ItemEvent`s are generated for the null-item in the JComboBox. How can I change this? Making the item `""` is not an option.

```
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ComboBoxTest {
   public static void main(String... args) {
       JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(new String[]{null, "one","two","three"});
       cb.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
       });
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, cb);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Null objects will not play nicely in a `JComboBox`. For example, the combo box's `getSelectedIndex` method, which is fired when you select an item, will return -1 if the object is `null`. There may also be other methods which perform null checks and may return incorrect results.

If you really need this functionality, it would be better to use wrapper objects. For example:

```
class StringWrapper{
    final String s;
    public StringWrapper(String s){
        this.s=s;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return s;
    }
}

final JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(new StringWrapper[]{ 
            new StringWrapper(null), 
            new StringWrapper("one"),
            new StringWrapper("two"),
            new StringWrapper("three")});
```

Comment: I didn't implemented it that way, but the hint regarding which methods misbehave was very useful...

Answer (score 2):

OK, I'm stupid... Just subclass JComboBox and add:

```
@Override
protected void selectedItemChanged() {
    fireItemStateChanged(new ItemEvent(this, ItemEvent.ITEM_STATE_CHANGED,
            selectedItemReminder,
            ItemEvent.DESELECTED));
    selectedItemReminder = dataModel.getSelectedItem();

    fireItemStateChanged(new ItemEvent(this, ItemEvent.ITEM_STATE_CHANGED,
            selectedItemReminder,
            ItemEvent.SELECTED));
}
```

I still think the described behavior of JComboBox is inconsistent and confusing...

Comment: This helped me out.  I had also overridden getSelectedIndex() to remove its checks for null.  The behavior is still slightly weird when arrowing to the item in the list, but other than that it's fine.  Here's the line in getSelectedIndex() that was changed: 
if (obj == sObject || (obj != null && obj.equals(sObject)))
 return i;

Answer (score 1):

If you want an action that fires once when an entry is selected, including null...

```
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ComboBoxTest {
   public static void main(String... args) {
       final JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(new String[]{null, "one","two","three"});
       cb.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED || cb.getSelectedItem() == null)
                System.out.println(e);
            }
       });
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, cb);
  }
}
```

Comment: `cb.getSelectedItem() == null` very well worked for me. However this is somewhat like hack because `e.getItem()` returns the previously selected item and `e.getStateChange()` evaluates `ItemEvent.DESELECTED`